# Should you always `module.export` a JS module?

Tags: javascript

I've seen the following in a few places recently and wondering why you'd need to export an empty objcet?

```
module.exports = {};
```

As an example, a module is a polyfill and only contains a self executing function.  What does the `module.exports = {}` at the end do?  Because the code seems to work with or without it (I can require the module as a dependency).

```
(function polyfillWindowLocationOrigin (location) {
    if (location.origin === undefined) {
        location.origin = location.protocol + '//' + location.host;
    }
})(window.location);

module.exports = {};
```

Note: We're using browserify.

Comment: If you say it works fine without it then it's not needed which make the question why is it needed hard to answer :)

Comment: I wondered if it was considered 'best practice' for some reason that I'm not aware of.  Maybe someone else had come across similar and knows why it may have been written that way.

Comment: Speaking personally, I just consider it as part of the 'boilerplate' code I put inside every module, even if I don't use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using the CommonJS module system then it can be assumed that this code appears at the start of each module:

```
var module = {
    exports: {}
};
```

So setting `module.exports = {};` accomplishes little technically, but may be preferable in terms of explicitly documenting the fact that the module exports nothing.

Comment: Being explicit is never a bad thing (: